# Adding totals at row level while using pivot table in python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have the dataset in below format. There are no missing values present.

```
Buyer/Spender,Channel,Region,Fresh,Milk,Grocery,Frozen,Detergents_Paper,Delicatessen
1,Retail,Other,12669,9656,7561,214,2674,1338
9,Hotel,Other,5963,3648,6192,425,1716,750
```

Using pivot table I could frame below details

```
summary=pd.pivot_table(Annual_Spending, values=['Fresh','Milk','Grocery','Frozen','Detergents_Paper','Delicatessen'], index=['Region','Channel'],  aggfunc=sum, margins=all)

summary

Region  Channel Delicatessen    Detergents_Paper    Fresh   Frozen  Grocery Milk                    
Lisbon  Hotel   70632               56081           761233  184512  237542  228342
        Retail  33695               148055          93600   46514   332495  194112
Oporto  Hotel   30965               13516           326215  160861  123074  64519
        Retail  23541               159795          138506  29271   310200  174625
Other   Hotel   320358              165990          2928269 771606  820101  735753
        Retail  191752              724420          1032308 158886  1675150 1153006
All             670943              1267857         5280131 1351650 3498562 2550357
```

As of now I am getting totals at the column level. I am trying to figure out how can I add totals at row level. I tried multiple options but most of the options gives subtotals at every index level.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure if you set `margins=True` instead of all that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, as @Oupkar Sandhu answered, `margins=True` sums up the rows as well, but I believe that each column in this data is considered to be an independent column and the row totals are not calculated. I think it's a good idea to add column totals (my guess, but...).

```
summary=(pd.pivot_table(Annual_Spending, values=['Fresh','Milk','Grocery','Frozen','Detergents_Paper','Delicatessen'],
                        index=['Region','Channel'], aggfunc='sum', margins=all))
summary['Total'] = summary.sum(axis=1)

        Delicatessen    Detergents_Paper    Fresh   Frozen  Grocery Milk    Total
Region  Channel                         
Other   Hotel   750 1716    5963    425 6192    3648    18694
Retail  1338    2674    12669   214 7561    9656    34112
All     2088    4390    18632   639 13753   13304   52806
```